# Server side paging with breeze

Tags: asp.net, breeze, paging

is there any sample/article on how to use server side paging with breeze.js?

I found that we may use PageSize from OData:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2013/02/19/paging-with-asp-net-web-api-odata.aspx

but I would really like to control my data paging (e.g. using PagedList):
https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Can you point me any article, idea or source code on how to achieve this?

thanks